# Connect to Oauth without User Interaction [QuickBooks]

Tags: c#, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Please Let me Know how to accomplish my task, connecting to Oauth without any interaction of the user and also the Oauth should not be expire or any way to prevent it from expire.

it would be great if you can provide me detailed code in c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. It's impossible.

Intuit requires that the user be involved in the OAuth process. They must click the [Connect to QuickBooks] button at least ONCE to go through the OAuth process and get the OAuth tokens.

Additionally, Intuit forces OAuth token expiration after 180 days. You can refresh/renew the token within 30 days of the expiration.

Please go read the documentation, where this is all very clearly explained:

- https://developer.intuit.com